# How can I make the page reload with Html5 or Jquery when the user click on a picture

Tags: jquery, html, user-controls, reload

I'm looking for a code that can make the user reload the page by clicking on something.
I'm really fresh in Web and don't know how to do it.

When the User is clicking on a picture it will show the picture for X seconds then reload the page (to initial position : top).

Or if you know a JQuery animation ready to use, it would be easy to incorporate

In hope that you can help me. Thanks you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is attach an `onclick()` handler to the image, and then reload the window. To achieve a delay, you can use `setTimeout()`. The `3000` in the following example correlates to 3000 milliseconds, or 3 seconds. You can adjust to suit :)

```js
document.getElementById("sample").onclick = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload();
  }, 3000);
}
```

```html
<img id="sample" src="http://placehold.it/100">
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It's great, is it possible to add a set timeout ? and how please ?

Comment: Absolutely! I've just updated my answer to cover this :)

Comment: Haha ! I find it by my self at the same moment, but thanks you a lot for your help.

And by the same way it help me to verify mine :)

Comment: No problem; glad you worked it out. And yes, it's not too difficult when you think about it logically ;)

Answer (score 2):

> syntax:
>       location.reload(forceGet) 
>       if forceGet=true means it reloads from server, 
>       forceGet=false means it reloads from cache

```
  <body>

<img onclick="myFunction() src="<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5IqA.png" >

<script>
function myFunction() {
    location.reload();
}
</script>

</body>
```